# Youtube Data API: I get a Quota Exceeded error with a new project

Tags: youtube-data-api

I was told Google Supporters monitor this forum, so I hope you can help:

I am unable to perform actions with the Youtube Data API, I get a "Quota Exceeded" error every time. I only use it for testing and only perform a single task like "Create Playlist".  OAuth Authorization worked fine. Tried creating an additional project - same result. I found the Quotas tab in my Settings but I can only see BigQuery stuff, not anything related to the Youtube API

Testing with the sample from here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#create_a_playlist

I did of course do my research, but none of the other questions offered a solution.

How do I solve this?

Comment: AFAIK there are random quota exceeded error, what are the features like "creating a playlist" that you are interested in ?

Comment: I was just checking if was able to connect to the Youtube Data API at all :) I know the code is working, because it's one of the official examples, which have worked before.

Comment: Ok I was just trying to tell you that we can use workarounds in order not to use YouTube Data API v3 which sometimes randomly bugs. If you're still having headaches if you precise the features you are interested in, I can tell you some workarounds.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Ah, I see :D - well, I just need to make a gallery of videos, listing each video from a public playlist - there is a large portion of videos, so I need to be able to use paging. I think in the past a public channel had a RSS feed with all videos associated to a playlist? If it still exists, I could just parse that

Comment: Okay, got it - https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=[Playlist ID]
from here  [StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79294)

Comment: Maybe I just don't know how to use RSS feed with the link you provided, but for a long playlist you doesn't seem able to retrieve the whole playlist content, isn't it a problem for you ?

Comment: Yes :) Investigating further, I found out that the feed isn't CORS-enabled, so it's difficult to retrieve

Comment: I don't know how much quota you need but for a normal use it should be largely enough, I added to my [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/) a free access, without to have to provide a key, to all YouTube Data API v3 public features. For instance for listing the videos in a playlist you can simply use: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLAYLIST_ID If you want to discuss about some details don't hesitate to join the [Discord](https://discord.gg/pDzafhGWzf) of the API. I have another workaround if it's still not ok.